# Не работает if после input внутри него

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Приношу извинения за вероятно глупый вопрос. Но не могу понять, почему после последнего input-а внутри if (*space = input(mars2+" И вы совершенно правы! Готовы ли вы вступить в космическую команду? Ответьте Да или Нет:")*) не работают все следующие проверки if. В чем моя ошибка?

```
gender = input("Ваш пол:")
age = input("Ваш возраст:")
pet = input("У вас есть домашние животные? Ответье Да или Нет:")
mars = input("Есть ли жизнь на Марсе? Ответьте Да или Нет:")

if pet == "Да":
    pet2 = "Есть"
else:
    pet2 = "Нет"

if mars == "Да":
    mars2 = "На Марсе есть жизнь!"
else:
    mars2 = "На Марсе нет жизни?"


print("Gender: " + gender)
print("Age: " + age)
print("Pet: " + pet2)

if mars == "Да":
    space = input(mars2+" И вы совершенно правы! Готовы ли вы вступить в космическую команду? Ответьте Да или Нет:")

if space == "Да" and pet == "Да":
    print=("Поздравляем! Космический командир свяжется с вами в ближайшие сутки. Ваши домашние животные будут направлены в космическую гостиницу на время экспедиции.")
    
if space == "Да" and pet == "Нет":
    print=("Поздравляем! Космический командир свяжется с вами в ближайшие сутки.")

if space == "Нет":
    print=("Очень жаль! Справимся без вас!")

if mars == "Нет":
    print(mars2+" К сожалению, вы ошиблись.☠️ Мы не пригласим вас в космическую экспедицию!")
```

Comment: что такое ```print=``` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` - это функция для вывода, а вы в переменную `print` записываете строки и ждете их в консоли...  измениете на `print()` и все заработает:

```
Ваш пол:>? М
Ваш возраст:>? 42
У вас есть домашние животные? Ответье Да или Нет:>? Да
Есть ли жизнь на Марсе? Ответьте Да или Нет:>? Да
Gender: М
Age: 42
Pet: Есть
На Марсе есть жизнь! И вы совершенно правы! Готовы ли вы вступить в космическую команду? Ответьте Да или Нет:>? Да
Поздравляем! Космический командир свяжется с вами в ближайшие сутки. Ваши домашние животные будут направлены в космическую гостиницу на время экспедиции.
```